# npm postinstall grunt bower task - ECMDERR

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, bower

I'm trying to run `grunt setup` (an alias for various tasks including a `bower-install-simple` task) via `npm postinstall`. Everything is all good until `bower` executes, where I get `ECMDERR Failed to execute...` when installing `jQuery` (the only package to be installed). The task runs from the command line with no problems. Here's the full message:

```
> w202_u17_a1@1.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\ap7466\Work\1. WIP\w202\w202_u17_a1
> grunt setup

Running "replace:bower" (replace) task

Running "replace:html" (replace) task

Running "replace:xml" (replace) task

Running "bower-install-simple:prod" (bower-install-simple) task
Executing Bower (Command: install)
bower jquery#>=1.0 <2.0         cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.3
bower jquery#>=1.0 <2.0       validate 1.11.3 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>=1.0 <2.0
bower jquery#>=1.0 <2.0        ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error
Warning: Task "bower-install-simple:prod" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

npm ERR! w202_u17_a1@1.0.0 postinstall: `grunt setup`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the w202_u17_a1@1.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the w202_u17_a1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     grunt setup
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls w202_u17_a1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\ap7466\Work\1. WIP\w202\w202_u17_a1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ap7466\Work\1. WIP\w202\w202_u17_a1\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have a proxy set in my `.gitconfig` and use `https://` instead of `git://`. Any advice would be much appreciated.